# Desktop configuration file cannot launch Android Studio in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: android-studio, terminal, launcher, ubuntu-15.10

I did not want to launch Android Studio from terminal, so I wrote the following `android-studio.desktop` file

```
 [Desktop Entry]
 Version=1.0
 Type=Application
 Name=Android Studio
 Exec=sh /home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
 Icon=/home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.png
 Categories=Development;IDE;
 Terminal=false
```

and saved it in Desktop. I permitted this file to be executed as a program. After all that done, double-clicking the Android Studio icon is not launching the IDE. But when I run `sh /home/ashraf/tools/android/android-studio/bin/studio.sh` from terminal, it launches. I am in **GNOME DE**. Help me out. I would like to fix this file only, no other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the Exec property

```
Exec=bash -i "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f
```

This is my android-studio.desktop, if it can help you :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Android Studio
Comment=Android Studio
Exec=bash -i "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh" %f 
Icon=/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.ico 
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-android-studio
Name[en_GB]=android-studio.desktop
```